# including headers files getting compilation errors

Tags: c++, include

I don't know if I have a circular inclusion problem or not.  I have three headers files:

```
file A:  needs files B and C
file B:  needs file A
file C:  needs files A and B
```

I've tried different ways of including files, and have include guards on each header file.  But I still get compilation errors with each way I try. Is it possible to make this work with includes?

Comment: I always try to avoid using includes in header files. You are creating a circular include here.

Comment: Check if fwd declaration can help reducing the dependency.

Comment: #include guards should have solved it, can you copy/paste the source files in here?

Comment: If you post some code in your question or in pastebin, we can give you more exact assistance.  Also include the compiler errors.

Comment: With circular dependencies you probably need forward declarations to break the dependency.

Comment: Then can you forward declare structs?  All three files have them.  Thanks for your fast answers.

Comment: @Jane Yes, you can forward declare structs, it doesn't even matter if `class` or `struct` keyword is used in the forward declaration.

Comment: Oh okay you would have to use pointers then?

Comment: A smart pointer or reference are common. The linked duplicate should explain that.

Comment: Would declaring the struct variables as externs also work?

Comment: ***Would declaring the struct variables as externs also work?*** No.

Answer (score 3):

You have clearly described a circular dependency.  Have you tried using forward declarations?